# MAX Status with lookup value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the query:

```
SELECT p.PROJ, p.lookup_PROJ_STATUS_ID, l.PROJ_STATUS_CD 
FROM PROJECT p 
LEFT JOIN LOOKUP_PROJ_STATUS l ON p.lookup_PROJ_STATUS_ID = l.lookup_JCN_STATUS_ID WHERE PROJ = '1703243'
```

Which results in
[Results 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF2pu.png)

I then query:

```
SELECT p.PROJ, MAX(p.lookup_PROJ_STATUS_ID) 
FROM PROJECT p 
WHERE PROJ = '1703243' 
GROUP BY PROJ
```

which results in
PROJ       MAX(p.lookup_PROJ_STATUS_ID)

1703243                               6

I would like to have the results show
PROJ       MAX(p.lookup_PROJ_STATUS_ID)    PROJ_STATUS_CD

1703243                               6                 R

I tried to do a subquery:

```
SELECT p.PROJ, MAX(p.lookup_PROJ_STATUS_ID) 
FROM PROJECT p 
WHERE PROJ = '1703243' 
GROUP BY PROJ, (SELECT LOOKUP_PROJ_STATUS l 
                WHERE p.lookup_PROJ_STATUS_ID = l.lookup_PROJ_STATUS)
```

which results in an error of missing expression

Comment: Hi - please don’t link to images, add all information to your question as editable text. Also, please format your SQL as code

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to create a CTE which ranks rows per each `proj`, sorted by `lookup_proj_status_id` in descending order, and then fetching the one(s) that rank as the highest.

```
with temp as
  (select p.proj, p.lookup_proj_status_id, l.proj_status_cd,
     rank() over (partition by p.proj order by p.lookup_proj_status_id desc) rnk
   from project p left join lookup_proj_status l on p.lookup_proj_status_id = l.lookup_jcn_status_id 
   where proj = '1703243'
   )
select proj, lookup_proj_status_id, proj_status_cd
from temp
where rnk = 1;
```

---

As of comment you posted (that there's *nothing* for `rnk = 1`): well, that's hard to believe. Rows are ranked, and rank #1 exists. Certain values might not to be returned (if there are ties):

This is your "result" (by the way, screenshot column names don't match the ones you posted in a query so ... you aren't talking the truth, entirely):

```
SQL> with result (proj, lookup_proj_status_id, proj_status_cd) as
  2    (select 1703243, 4, 'P' from dual union all
  3     select 1703243, 5, 'S' from dual union all
  4     select 1703243, 5, 'S' from dual union all
  5     select 1703243, 6, 'R' from dual
  6    )
  7  select lookup_proj_status_id, proj_status_Cd,
  8          rank() over (partition by proj order by lookup_proj_status_id desc) rnk,
  9    dense_rank() over (partition by proj order by lookup_proj_status_id desc) drnk
 10  from result;

LOOKUP_PROJ_STATUS_ID PROJ_STATUS_CD         RNK       DRNK
--------------------- --------------- ---------- ----------
                    6 R                        1          1   --> #1
                    5 S                        2          2
                    5 S                        2          2
                    4 P                        4          3

SQL>
```

If your result is #2, no problem, use that condition (i.e. `where rnk = 2`).

Without a CTE? Why, what's wrong with a CTE? You could put that code into a subquery, but that's more or less just the same.

Comment: I tried this and rnk = 1 is blank, my answer was actually with rnk = 2.  Any thoughts on this?  Also, would like this to be a part of a bigger SQL query, is there a way to do this without CTE?

Comment: If you run this SQL without the final “ where rnk = 1” do you not see a record where rank = 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `inner join` to join with the subquery that's helped to find the MAX lookup :

```
with cte as (
  SELECT PROJ, MAX(lookup_PROJ_STATUS_ID) as max_lookup_PROJ_STATUS_ID
  FROM PROJECT 
  WHERE PROJ = '1703243' 
  GROUP BY PROJ
) 
select t.*
from cte c
inner join PROJECT t on t.PROJ = c.PROJ and t.lookup_PROJ_STATUS_ID = c.max_lookup_PROJ_STATUS_ID
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/X00S6Emf)

Answer (score 0):

Though all the given answers are correct, But just to give you an oracle specific answer to your question, You can try max function with [KEEP](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_FP499O87G9NJ3CA3JKIJA5XM8.html) predicate -

```
SELECT MAX(PROJ) KEEP(DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY lookup_PROJ_STATUS_ID DESC) PROJ,
       MAX(lookup_PROJ_STATUS_ID) lookup_PROJ_STATUS_ID,
       MAX(PROJ_STATUS_CD) KEEP(DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY lookup_PROJ_STATUS_ID DESC) PROJ_STATUS_CD
from PROJECT t
WHERE PROJ = '1703243';
```